# Name and proper notation for multidimensional systematic sampling

Tags: notation, terminology, sampling

I'm trying to find the official name and formulation of the following sampling technique. I believe it is simply referred to as "systematic sampling", but failed to find a reference describing it precisely for more than one dimension.

For one dimension, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systematic_sampling) or this [site](https://explorable.com/systematic-sampling) describe it well: 1. pick a starting number, 2. then pick an interval, and the sampled points are simply each member of the population starting from the first, then periodically adding the interval to find the next sample.

More concretely, I tried expressing it for **one dimension** `x`:

Let `n` the requested number of samples, and  `x_max` and `x_min` the bounds of the population

$$
samples = (x_\text{min} + \frac{x_\text{max} - x_\text{min}}{n-1}\cdot i)_{i=0}^\text{n}
$$

E.g. for `n=5` samples between `0` and `1`, the samples would be

```
{0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1}
```

For **two dimensions** `(x,y)`, I would propose the following notation (although I am not sure if the term "systematic sampling" would still apply):

$$
samples = \bigg((x_\text{min} + \frac{x_\text{max} - x_\text{min}}{n-1}\cdot i)_{i=0}^\text{n}, \quad (y_\text{min} + \frac{y_\text{max} - y_\text{min}}{m-1}\cdot i)_{i=0}^\text{m} \bigg)
$$

Where e.g. for `x` and `y` between `0` and `1`, and `n=5` and `m=3`:

```
{ 
 (0, 0),
 (0.25, 0),
 (0.5, 0),
 (0.75, 0),
 (1, 0),
 (0, 0.5),
 (0.25, 0.5),
 (0.5, 0.5),
 (0.75, 0.5),
 (0, 1),
 (0.25, 1),
 (0.5, 1),
 (0.75, 1)
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is it clear from my notation that the combination of sequences for `x`
   and `y` is performed with the same order as in the example (i.e. first vary all `x` for a
   constant `y` before incrementing `y`), and if not, is there a way to indicate this?
2. What would be a proper mathematical notation for this in `n`
   dimensions?
3. Is it correct to call this "systematic sampling" for more than one dimension, or is there another name to describe it?

Comment: (1) The sequence of samples is usually considered separately from the locations of the samples.  (2) In two and more dimensions, a grid of sample points like this need not be square: it can be rectangular, rotated, and even skewed.  The mathematics of this concerns [Lattices.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(discrete_subgroup))

Comment: (3) Yes, this is an example of what is called "systematic sampling."  See, for instance, Richard Gilbert, [Statistical Methods for Environmental Pollution Monitoring](https://www.osti.gov/biblio/7037501-statistical-methods-environmental-pollution-monitoring) (the link goes to a legitimate scanned copy).

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the book and lattice references, very relevant! Unfortunately, Gilbert is also not explicit on the "order" with which samples are taken. I'm not familiar with lattices, but it seems based on the [wiki picture](https://goo.gl/EPYKUE) that lattices are associated with order. Would you be able to (or think it would be possible to) propose a formulation based on lattices to express the sampling locations **and** their order? Maybe it is obvious enough that I can explain it in text, but if there is a proper formulation I'd prefer that.

Comment: Lattices are not associated with "order" in the sense you mean--they are related to a number-theoretic concept called an "order," and that's a completely different thing. Statisticians separate the concepts of  *selection of sampling locations* from the *sequence in which they're visited,* because both involve somewhat different considerations. In practice, it is rare for the sequence to be specified because many people believe (perhaps unreasonably) that it doesn't matter.  Regardless, you specify the sequence by ... listing the sample locations. It's that simple.

Comment: @whuber Ok, thanks for clarifying. So you suggest simply listing an example like ´(x1 y1, x1 y2, ..., x2 y1, x2 y2, ..., xn y1, xn y2, ..., xn ym)´, and "easily generalizing to p dimensions"? If you'd like to repost you replies  as answer I'd accept them.